# IntelliJ running a program with Gradle, "failed at task :Run" error

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

Here is the error that I am getting whenever I try to run my program with Gradle. (I am on a linux ubuntu system, if that matters) I am using a JDK 11 version to run this.

```
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/home/dex/Downloads/jdk-11.0.13/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Exception -

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':run'
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/dex/Downloads/jdk-11.0.13/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

UPDATED (./gradlew run command)

```
> Configure project :
Project : => no module-info.java found

> Task :compileJava
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :run FAILED
Redirected Output: logs/master_log_3_9_2022_10_38_38.txt

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
5 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

From --debug(Only posted info that was in red)

```
2022-03-09T13:01:57.117-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 4s


2022-03-09T13:01:57.116-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

2022-03-09T13:01:56.807-0500 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] > Task :run FAILED

2022-03-09T13:01:57.116-0500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

From log master file

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at Main.main(Main.java:210)
    at KioskApp.main(KioskApp.java:5)
```

Comment: Post full output when you run this task from the command line by Gradle: e.g. it might be the `./gradlew run`. Also, add the `--debug` [option](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html#logLevels) as the command argument to have Gradle to make more verbose output.

Comment: "> Task :run FAILED
Redirected Output: logs/master_log_3_9_2022_10_38_38.txt" and "Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output" (both in the error message) might be helpful

Comment: doesnt --debug show info I should not post?